# How to determine the kind of mistake in a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I am reaching a deadline at one of my projects and I am kind of stuck so I will need your help. The homework is all about making a spell checker in **Prolog** which will use an input of lists with letters and output the corrected lists. I will be given the correct words in a format like this:

```
word([t,h,e]).
word([h,e,l,l,o]).
word([w,o,r,l,d]).
```

The errors I should check about are

1. One letter error. Example: [t,h,a] -> [t,h,e].
2. One letter missing. Example: [h,e,l,l] -> [h,e,l,l,o].
3. One letter extra. Example: [w,o,l,r,l,d] -> [w,o,r,l,d]

I already have the code for each kind of correction but I have to run every single rule for each word and get multiple results of which only 1 is the correct one. Is there any way to determine what the error is in the word given and run only the appropriate rule in order to correct it?

Comment: I don't think that you can always determine the error; for example `hel` could be either `hell` (one letter missing) or `he` (one extra letter). You mentioned that you get multiple results and only 1 is correct; could you post an example?

Comment: @thanosQR The words I will be given will have no such similarities so there is not a possibility to mistake one word with another. For example let's say this is the prompt:

?-checker([[t,h,e],[w,o,l,r,l,d]],X).

X=[[t,h,e],[w,o,l,r,l,d]];  % Using the one letter error.

X=[[t,h,e],[w,o,l,r,l,d]];  % Using the one letter missing.

X=[[t,h,e],[w,o,r,l,d]];    % Using the one letter extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just need a disjunction :

```
my_correction(Word) :-
    (
        correction1(Word, Result)
    ;
        correction2(Word, Result)
    ;
        correction3(Word, Result)
    ),
    % do stuff with Result.
```

Or maybe I misunderstood your problem...

You may want to wrap this in a if structure for the case where a correction isn't needed :

```
my_correction(Word) :-
    (   \+ (correction1(Word, Result);correction2(Word, Result);correction3(Word, Result))
     -> Result = Word
     ;  true),
    % do stuff with Result.
```

(that says that if no correction has been needed, Result = Word, else, Result is already holding the correcting word, so just return true).

Comment: That would do it Mog. Well not all of it but I noticed that if I use the code you provided in the beggining along with all my rules seperated by ; then the very first result I will take is the correct one. Although I don't know why is that happening is there any way just to keep the first result as long as it's correct? A way to stop the recursion I mean

Comment: yup, you can call once(my_correction) or use a cut after it (my_correction(X), !, % rest...

Comment: Thanks, a ! just before the recursion fixed the problem by showing only 1 result. I hope that will pass. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of a simple spellchecker in Prolog:

https://github.com/Attempto/APE/blob/master/lexicon/spellcheck.pl

Comment: That could help me but I don't want to copy something, I want to get the point really. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: The given link has changed to this : https://github.com/Attempto/APE/tree/master/prolog/lexicon/spellcheck.pl